# DateTime required in ModelState, however never set to be

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I have a DateTime field in my form. For whatever reason, everytime I submit the form ModelState comes back as invalid and a message that my date time field (called PostDate) is required, even though in the view model I don't have the required attribute set.

Does anyone know why this would be happening as I'm going around in circles trying to figure it out.

Here is the view model

```
public class BlogViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string Title { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Content { get; set; }
            public bool Published { get; set; }
            public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the controller actions

```
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            } 

            //
            // POST: /Admin/Blog/Create

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateInput(false)]
            public ActionResult Create(BlogViewModel model)
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    model.Content = HtmlSanitizer.SanitizeHtml(model.Content);
                    Services.BlogService.CreateBlogPost(model.Title, model.Content, User.Identity.Name);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(model);
            }
```

Here is the View

```
    @using Payntbrush.Infrastructure.Mvc.Extensions
    @model Payntbrush.Presentation.Demo.MVC3.Areas.Admin.Models.BlogViewModel

    @Html.Resource(Html.ScriptTag("Areas/Admin/js/plugins/wysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js"), ResourceType.Js)


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, "Blog", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "BlogEditor" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "wysiwyg blog-editor" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Time of post (Only set this if you want to make a post appear to have been published at a different date.)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostDate, new{@class="datetimepicker"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostDate)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Published (Check to make this post live on the site)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Published)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Published)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input class="large awesome" type="submit" value="Create" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Blog", null, new { @class = "large awesome cancel-button" })
            </p>
    }

    <div>

    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried using `DateTime?` instead?

Comment: That was it, thanks Nico

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you leave the corresponding field empty your model will be invalid because DateTime is a value type. You should use a nullable DateTime if you want to allow empty values:

```
public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
```